# AngularJS directive with ng-show not toggling with change in variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a simple html5 video playlist app. I've got an overlay div on top of the html5 video that should appear/disappear when stopping and starting the video.

I've got ng-show and a variable to trigger it, but it's not changing when I look using ng-inspector.

My events might not be quite correct, either - but I can't seem to find much information on putting events on different elements within the same directive. Is this a clue that I should break this up into multiple directives?

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('campaignController', campaignController)
    .directive('myVideo', myvideo);

    function campaignController($log,Campaign) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.overlay = true;

        Campaign.getCampaign().success(function(data) {
            vm.campaign = data[0];
            vm.item = vm.campaign.videos[0];
        });

        vm.select = function(item) {
            vm.item = item;

        };

        vm.isActive = function(item) {
            return vm.item === item;
        };
    };

    function myvideo() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',

            template: ['<div class="video-overlay" ng-show="vm.overlay">',
            '<p>{{ vm.campaign.name}}</p>',
            '<img class="start" src="play.png">',
            '</div>',
            '<video class="video1" controls ng-src="{{ vm.item.video_mp4_url | trusted }}" type="video/mp4"></source>',
            '</video>' ].join(''),
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.video = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("video1")[0]);
                scope.startbutton = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("start")[0]);


                scope.startbutton.on('click', function() {
                    scope.vm.overlay = false;
                    scope.video[0].play();

                });
                scope.video.on('click', function() {
                    scope.video[0].pause();
                    scope.vm.overlay = true;
                });

            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: how come `scope.vm` will have value?

Comment: @PankajParkar `var vm = this` is controller and all the properties of `vm` can be accessed directly in view using the alias for controller. This is a better practice than scope

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh I know that sir, I asked `scope.vm` would not have a value..

Comment: maybe it's related with using `this` instead of `$scope`? I'm not sure if that what is assigned to `this` is available for child scopes.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience angular expression evaluation does not work as javascript. so try ng-show="vm.overlay==true".

Furthermore you bind click using native javascript.

Either don't do that and use ng-click or call scope.$apply() in the click event t callbackas last intruction (even though i'm not sure if it's really important).

Comment: I've never had problems with `ng-show="expression"`. But you're right with the second part of your answer. He must call `scope.$apply()` in his click handlers.

Comment: i think i got more trouble with expression like !<textVariable> or !<array.length> but i don't remember. So i always write the full expression now :P